# ASP.Net Core 3.1 - passing value to partial view Modal with Ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

I want to delete a record from table and I have to send the ID of that record to the modal, how I do this?

main View :

```
<tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
           <tr>
                <td> @rowCount</td>
                <td>@item.CategoryTitle</td>
                <td>@item.IconCategory</td>
                <td>
                   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Deletemodal" asp-route- 
                   category="@item.CategoryId" title="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
                   xs">delete</a>
                 </td>
            </tr>
                       
         }
  </tbody>
```

Partial view as a Modal:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_CreateMainCategory")
```

Comment: You can try to dynamically load partial view in modal in ajax success callback function.

Comment: thanks, can u help me with code? I'm not good in ajax

Comment: `can u help me with code? I'm not good in ajax` Hi @AliKhansari, you can check the sample code that I shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to delete a record from table and I have to send the ID of that record to the modal, how I do this?

To achieve your requirement, you can try to dynamically load partial view in your modal, like below.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Deletemodal" title="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
   onclick="Func_LoadPv(@item.CategoryId)">delete</a>
```

*Html code of modal popup*

```
<div id="Deletemodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @*modal body here*@
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

*JS function*

```
<script>
    function Func_LoadPv(Cid) {
        $.get("/Home/ShowPartialView?CategoryId=" + Cid, function (res) {
            $("div.modal-body").append(res);
        });
    }
</script>
```

*Action method*

```
public IActionResult ShowPartialView(int CategoryId)
{
    return PartialView("_CreateMainCategory", CategoryId);
}
```

Comment: The modal opens but does not enter the controller
`$.get("/AdminPanel/Category/ShowPartialView?CategoryId=" + Cid, function (res) {
                $("div.modal-body").append(res);
            });`
`AdminPanel` is area

Comment: there is error in Console :
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` In Console tab, you can try to find which code snippet cause the error.

Comment: Displays the `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Deletemodal" onclick="Func_LoadPv(59ccfd4a-39cd-4c1a-813b-0405b05d0eb4)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">delete</a>` tag as an error

Comment: Ok, it seems that the `CategoryId` you passed would be a Guid, you can try to modify the code as `onclick="Func_LoadPv('@item.CategoryId')"`. And modify your action method accept a Guid-type parameter.

Comment: I Changed ...`public IActionResult ShowPartialView(Guid CategoryId)
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateMainCategory", CategoryId);
        }` But there is still  error

Comment: Have you changed the html part with `onclick="Func_LoadPv('@item.CategoryId')"`?

Comment: it's worked thanks . How do I get the `CategoryId` in Modal?

Comment: Can be used only once. The modal will not open a second time?

Comment: If possible, you can accept the solution as answer, then create a new thread for your new question.